# Make Sitecore Workflow comments mandatory

Tags: sitecore-client, workflow

In Sitecore 9 Workflow, i wish to make the comments mandatory for some actions. While surfing i came across the below solution

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895043/sitecore-workbox-make-comment-textbox-required

and this worked perfect.

Anyways, I'm eager to check if there is any other option in sitecore to accomplish this without any custom code. I tried few things like duplicating the default comments template(Standard Comment Template) and assigning the **Required** validation rule for the **Comments** field.

Below is the screenshot of my validation rule,

[image: validation rule]

and i assigned this rule to my comments field
[image: mapping]

But while executing the action without giving comments , I just got the warning pop up message which in turn allowed to press OK and the command executed. But my expectation is to abort the process if comments is not filled.

[image: warning popup]

Please suggest any idea to achieve this.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of how you defined the validation rule.

Comment: @Jen , included the screenshots

Comment: It’s a bug in sitecore it seems. You can get the patch upgrade from sitecore support. 

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sitecore-workflow-custom-comment-template-issue-few-rohit-chopra

Comment: yes @sai. you are right. thank u

Answer (score 1):

Here is direct link to mentioned patch https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.196255/releases/tag/8.2.0.0

Have the same issue in Sitecore 9.3. This patch helped to resolve it.